# Add custom Icons to Ionic Framework on Intel XDK

Tags: ionic-framework, icons

Please, looking for a tutorial or explanation that can guide me how to add custom icons to ionic framework. Tried a lot to use custom icons however couldn't understand how the framework make use of the icons in order to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own icons including custom fonts in your project generated from sites like [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/#app-features), [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) or similar.

From these sites you can download a pack with font files (ttf, svg, ...) and relating CSS file. Generally they provide also a demo.html.

It's often necessary to customize the CSS in order to avoid overlapping to Ionicons. For example a CSS could be similar to the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myicons';
    src:url('../fonts/myicons.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/myicons.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/myicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/myicons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/myicons.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.icon-camera:before {
    font-family: 'myicons';
    content: "\e607";
}
.icon-video-camera:before {
    font-family: 'myicons';
    content: "\e608";
}
.icon-price-tag:before {
    font-family: 'myicons';
    content: "\e609";
}
```

Comment: Hi Beaver. That is absolutely what I was looking for. thank you.